# composer/laravel -- mbstring: installed, available, but not seen by laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

Question: How does composer/laravel know, or not know, that mbstring is installed? What do I need to do to point composer/laravel at mbstring?

Trying to install latest / greatest larvel onto a RHEL server.  mbstring is installed and enabled in both GUI and CLI.

ie cli:

```
/usr/bin/php -v:
PHP 5.5.24 (cli) (built: Apr 18 2015 03:23:49)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

and

```
/usr/bin/php -m
[PHP Modules]
...
mbstring
mcrypt
...
```

Yet when I do this:

```
$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel dev-laravel
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.15)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.15)
    Loading from cache
```

I get this:

```
Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.2.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
```

Well, I get like 20 of them.

I have searched stack/web and everybody solves the issue of "installing" mbstring ... That's not my problem.  I know it working based upon using code that requires mbstring to be installed and working.

The only thing that seems wrong is that in php.ini extension_dir is not enabled.

ie:

```
 ; extension_dir = "./"
```

But enabling that breaks the current install.

So I am guessing that composer/laravel just can't find mbstring ...

Comment: What do you get if you run `php -i | grep mbstring`?

Comment: Use `composer show -p` to list the so-called "PlatformRepository", which is the fake repository Composer uses to track versions for modules and includes, including PHP itself. The output there should indicate whether it correctly sees mbstring and how.

Comment: @anyber ... mbstring is present in both cli and gui .. but here is the -i   /usr/bin/php -i |grep mbstring
/etc/php.d/mbstring.ini,
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
mbstring
mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes ... composer show -p does *NOT* show ext-mbstring ... so the question is "How do I tell composer" where mbstring is?

Comment: Is it in the list when you enter `php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());"` on the command line? Also, since you enter `/usr/bin/php` explicitly with all commands - does `which php` also point there? Does `composer show -p` list PHP at version `5.5.24` as well?

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes ... indeed just "php" returns different results then "/usr/bin/php".  Nice catch ... all of our crons / cli stuff has the full path, so I never tried just "php" and it makes sense composer is trying just php.  I am not *fixed* yet, but I should be able to get it working from here.  Thanks.

Comment: Cheers :) was about only option hehe

Answer (score 0):

1. find your php.ini
2. make sure the directive extension_dir=C:\path\to\server\php\ext is
   set and adjust the path (set your PHP extension dir)
3. make sure the directive extension=php_mbstring.dll is set
   (uncommented)

Comment: The OP is using RHEL, not Windows.

Comment: Please note near the bottom where I said that enabling the extension_dir breaks the system